# Enabling Remi Repo on CentOS 5.6

Tags: centos, repository

I'm trying to enable the Remi repo on CentOS 5.6 but I'm getting an error message about a yum dependency on `rpm -Uvh`.

I'm following the instructions on repository configuration on this page: http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en  .

After I download both rpm packages and run `rpm -Uvh remi-release-5*.rpm epel-release-5*.rpm`, the Remi repo isn't successfully installed.

I get the following error message:

```
aviso: remi-release-5.rpm: Cabeçalho V3 assinatura DSA: NOKEY, key ID 00f97f56
erro: Dependências não satisfeitas:
    yum é requerido por remi-release-5.9-1.el5.remi.noarch
```

This message is in Portuguese.  Translated to English it would be something like:

```
Warning: remi-release-5.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 00f97f56
Error: unmet dependencies:
    yum is required by remi-release-5.9-1.el5.remi.noarch
```

Comment: Could you edit into your question the output of `rpm -qf /usr/bin/yum`?

Comment: o arquivo /usr/bin/yum não pertence a nenhum pacote. which would be something like: "/usr/bin/yum does not belong to any package"

Comment: There's your answer, then; you don't have the `yum` package installed, which is a mandatory requirement for using the remi repo.  I don't know where you got your `yum` binary from, but it's not from the right place; I'm afraid this is the sort of thing that happens when you start going *off-piste* for your software installations.

Comment: But I do have Yum. I use it all the time to install packages.
Is there anyway that rpm isn't finding yum. Epel repo installed successfully only remi got that error.

Comment: You might have the yum binary available, but your RPM database does not indicate that the yum *package* is installed.  How did you install CentOS?

Answer (score 1):

As asciiphil points out, the problem isn't that you don't have the yum binary, it's that you don't have the `yum` package, and remi's repo cares about the distinction. You could use `--nodeps` to force the install, and see what else breaks; but you might be better off getting to the bottom of this.  Did you install CentOS on this box, and if so, can you give us some insight into anything odd about the install?